# Firebase on/once synchronisation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to call a Firebase database with the ".on" function and call it again in a loop, for example like that:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  that.fireRef.child("users/"+uid+"/discussions").on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var groupKey = snapshot.key;
    console.log('OrdreUn');
    that.discussionsUsers.child(groupKey).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
      user=snapshot.key;
      console.log('OrdreDeux');
      if(user==firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      {
        user=true;
        resolve(groupKey);
      }
    });
    console.log('ForderUn');
  });
  console.log('ForderDeux');
});
```

The problem is that my console.log functions will show me that the execution is totally asynchronous, I don't know why but if I use `.once` function instead of `.on` function the execution is syncrhonized, the problem is that if I use `.once function` I can't access snapshot.key.

I would like to find the proper way to solve this problem.

Comment: I putted "Hi everybody" but doesn't appear at the beginning of my question :'(

Comment: Hey have you tried to use .then functions as `on` function itself returns promise so you can use then to synchronise the data

Answer (score 0):

you can use .then of since firebase itself returns promise which you can use to make next call to firebase to synchronise the data and get the result on basis of `groupkey` somewhat like this

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  that.fireRef.child("users/"+uid+"/discussions").on('child_added').then(snapshot => {
    var groupKey = snapshot.key;
    that.discussionsUsers.child(groupKey).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
      user=snapshot.key;
      console.log('OrdreDeux');
      if(user==firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      {
        user=true;
        resolve(groupKey);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu the problem is that when I do it like you suggest, we get the error .then() is not a function so I am not sure that it returns a promise.

Comment: Hi @Florent checkout edited code Also for reference view this [link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html)